# Two variables into 1 variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two variables that I am trying to make 1 variable.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

req = requests.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/4/02_03_2018/team-ratings/')
data = req.json()

for event in data:
    ed = event['EventDetails']
    prop = ed['Properties']
    home = prop['HomeTeamShort']
    away = prop['VisitorTeamShort']
    teams = home, away

    print(home,away)
```

**Results:**

```
PHI OTT
MTL ANA
WPG COL
NYI CLB
NJD PIT
FLA DET
BUF STL
BOS TOR
NAS NYR
DAL MIN
CGY CHI
VAN TB
LA ARI
```

With the `teams` variable above i would like to make them 1. How do i make it so both names are in the teams variable?

Comment: Create a dictionary and append them

Comment: What i was looking for was resolved by creating a dictionary like you mentioned. Then write a for loop to to extract them. Thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is, `teams` has this shape: `(home, away)`.

You could use a `join` statement to print the elements of `team` as a single string:

```
print(" ".join(teams))

>>>PHI OTT
```

Comment: with `print( "\n".join(teams))` was what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a dictionary for a little bit of hierarchy.

```
teams = {"home": home, "away": away}
```

This way you could reference them with the same variable, but they maintain their distinctiveness.

```
print(teams["home"] + " vs. " + teams["away"])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to concatenate the two values, and not access them separately, then you can just say

`teams = home + ' ' + away`